# When does GPIO peripheral get its members addresses assigned?

Tags: c, arm, stm32, stm32f4

From `stm32f446xx.h` we have a definition of GPIO_TypeDef

```
typedef struct
{
  __IO uint32_t MODER;    /*!< GPIO port mode register,               Address offset: 0x00      */
  __IO uint32_t OTYPER;   /*!< GPIO port output type register,        Address offset: 0x04      */
  __IO uint32_t OSPEEDR;  /*!< GPIO port output speed register,       Address offset: 0x08      */
  __IO uint32_t PUPDR;    /*!< GPIO port pull-up/pull-down register,  Address offset: 0x0C      */
  __IO uint32_t IDR;      /*!< GPIO port input data register,         Address offset: 0x10      */
  __IO uint32_t ODR;      /*!< GPIO port output data register,        Address offset: 0x14      */
  __IO uint32_t BSRR;     /*!< GPIO port bit set/reset register,      Address offset: 0x18      */
  __IO uint32_t LCKR;     /*!< GPIO port configuration lock register, Address offset: 0x1C      */
  __IO uint32_t AFR[2];   /*!< GPIO alternate function registers,     Address offset: 0x20-0x24 */
} GPIO_TypeDef;
```

This is used to initialize some GPIO peripherals. Focusing on GPIOA:

```
#define PERIPH_BASE           ((uint32_t)0x40000000)
#define AHB1PERIPH_BASE       (PERIPH_BASE + 0x00020000)
#define GPIOA_BASE            (AHB1PERIPH_BASE + 0x0000)
#define GPIOA               ((GPIO_TypeDef *) GPIOA_BASE)
```

So my questions are:

1. Is the `#define` directive declaring and initializing the struct and putting it at address pointed to at `GPIOA_BASE? Or is the define statement just declaring the struct but not initializing its members?
2. How do the members get their address placement correct without it being explicitly defined? How do we know that `GPIOA->MODER` leads to the same address as `GPIOA_BASE`? Likewise how do we know `GPIOA->ODR` leads to the address `GPIOA_BASE` + offset `0x014`? Is it simply because when we declare the struct and tell it that it's located at `GPIOA_BASE` with the `#define GPIOA               ((GPIO_TypeDef *) GPIOA_BASE)` command all it's member variables are declared and initialized in memory in the order they appear in the struct `GPIOA_TypeDef`? That would make sense since each takes 4 bytes but I am unsure if this is the case.
3. If the member variables are not declared in the order they are listed in the struct then how do they get their memory addresses assigned?

Comment: `Is the #define statement` ... `define` is a directive(macro definition)  and not a statemant

Comment: its doing what the code says.  the defines are creating (uint32_t)0x40020000; then GPI0A is a define of((GPIO_Typedef *)(uint32_t)0x400020000) with the right number of parens so that when you eventually use it.  pointing structures across compile domains is in general a really bad idea, but because so few or one compiler is used and its habits are known, this has become a habit.  Usually starts a flame war but it falls into implementation defined, not always works...all this is doing is a lazy way to create some defines that point at registers

Comment: the uint32_t is creating a 4 bytes per spacing between say MODER and OTYPER.  the defines are setting the base address of 0x40020000 so moder is 0x40020000 and OTYPER 0x40020004 in this case from what you have shown us.

Comment: @old_timer thanks! but how do we know where the member variables such as `MODER` and `ODR` are being correctly placed in the address we expect them to be? We are trusting them to be all next to each other and declared in the order we type them?

Comment: compile and disassemble as you should always do when using structures across compile domains.

Comment: @old_timer what do you mean "structures across compile domains" ?

Comment: the other how you know is that this is likely from ST even in CMSIS, and they tested it on one/few compilers

Comment: pointing a structure at memory, at data read from a file, at hardware are all different compile domains.  to safely use a structure you use the same compiler and pass the structure to other functions in that project or code. as soon as you use it across compile domains, pass it to a kernel driver, use it as a lazy way to parse data from a file, or in this case point at registers. It WILL bite you if you use it as a habit, it WILL require regular maintenance of the code.  this case is a lot safer in that it is using fixed sized, word sized elements through out and is not a  union with structs

Comment: @old_timer i am still having trouble understanding the concept of compile domains. Is there a place i can read more?

Comment: when you use the same compiler (binary) with the same settings for one or more files in the same project the compiler chooses how to layout the struct, they implement the alignment and packing, so all code produced from the same compiler on the same machine same day same project same settings will produce the same layout/packing and "just work", crossing to other compilers there is no reason to assume the same layout and packing and that it just works.

Comment: @old_timer when would you cross over to another compiler? you mean like use `gcc` to compile to object files and then `clang` to link it?

Comment: If I take an x86 compiler on my host computer and take some struct and compile code for it, the offsets into that struct where elements are and padding, etc are determined by that compiler, that is a compile domain the domain that that compiler controls.  if i take the same struct and build something for an arduino with even the same compiler or different (gcc for example) but a different target, avr instead of x86, there is no reason to assume that the offsets in the struct are the same and as a result if you move data between these two binaries these two programs and simply point the

Comment: structure at it the elements dont come out right.  to take that further when I produce logic based on yet another compiler (vhdl, verilog, cadence, synopsys, etc) those offsets are defined relative to each other and if you point at those you are crossing a compile domain between the compiler that produced the logic and the compiler that produced the mcu binary (not that the logic used structs, but the mcu side is a lazy approach at saving on typing and or doing more typing actually, depends).

Comment: structs like this are relatively safe, but when you get into bitfields then it all falls apart, likewise using a union with a struct with bitfields vs say a uint32_t.  very very bad, will bite you someday, generally a decade or two into your career when you change jobs, projects, or compilers or the world goes from 16 to 32 bit or 32 bit to 64 or 64 to 128.   stepping off the soapbox now.

Comment: the struct is just a list of words, the compiler implements them in order, being 32 bit words against that target relatively safe that they will stay aligned without padding esp with stdint although stdint does break the struct rules in the spec.  still relatively safe about as safe as you can be.  the defines are so they can modularize the building of addresses for whatever reason, bloat or sanity depends on the design and where these are used, these peripherals are re-used across this vendors chip families but at different base addresses.

Comment: so that sets up the hardcoded base address for this peripheral then C pointer magic to connect the two.  The best way to check though is build a small program even just an object and disassemble and see that it produced the right addresses for the registers in question

Comment: @old_timer thanks! that's very descriptive. But i still am having a hard time understanding why you would ever cross compile domains. do you have a real-life example i can read about?

Comment: @Taako same advise as in your another Topic. Learn the C language before asking such a questions a bit deeper. Buy a book. Study. Your questions just show that you are a very beginner.

Comment: @PeterJ_01 what is wrong with asking questions? I couldn't find the answer to this from googling it so apparently it's not a very common question and i don't see any book that says that compilers are not allowed to re-order struct members in memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name "C" is used to describe two things:

1. A family of languages which map source code constructs onto target-machine constructs in a rather consistent fashion.  There's often no "standard" documenting how such mapping should be performed, and implementations for unusual target platforms will behave differently from those for more common ones, but compilers for similar platforms will generally behave similarly.
2. A language which contains only the features mandated by the C11 Standard, and generally omits features which aren't implemented consistently on all platforms, even though C compilers for similar platforms would have processed them similarly.

The code you cite above is designed for compilers that process a languages in the first family, which is adapted to the needs of ARM processors.  In that language, each item of a structure will be placed at the lowest offset which satisfies its alignment requirement.  Neither the C11 Standard, nor any of its predecessors, requires that compilers guarantee to lay out structures in such fashion, nor do any of them even any convenient way for those that sometimes do otherwise to indicate that fact.  From the point of view of the C11 Standard, structure elements may be arbitrarily placed subject subject to relatively few constraints.  I think the authors of C89 probably figured that compiler writers would lay things out sequentially, with or without a mandate, except on rare platforms where there might be a compelling reason to do otherwise, and thus saw no reason to demand that they behave as they were going to anyway.  Some people, however, seem to believe the lack of a mandate was meant to be an open invitation to arrange things arbitrarily, and any code that would rely upon a particular layout should be viewed as "defective".

Comment: so we do "trust" that when the compiler sees the declaration of `GPIO_TypeDef *` at address `GPIOA_BASE` it will initialize its member variables `MODER`, `ODR`, etc... sequentially and in the order they appear in the structure? And we also trust that because they are `uint32` that they align correctly to the registers in the reference manual?

Comment: @Taako: Pretty much.  Any compiler that is suitable for embedded systems use on the ARM platform will behave in such fashion, and code which would rely upon the ability to access I/O registers cannot be expected to behave usefully on compilers that aren't suitable for such use.

Comment: okay, i understand. thanks for the explanation. I guess i had a philosophical issue with the lack of address being explicitly spelled out in memory but i suppose it shouldn't really be an issue

Comment: @Taako: IMHO, the Standard should have long ago specified a syntax for placing objects at specific offsets within structures, but I think the fact that compilers were nearly 100% consistent in how they processed structure layouts in cases when all members would naturally be optimally aligned for their respective data types meant that the ordinary struct-member syntax was generally sufficient to fit the needs of even system-level programmers.

Comment: is the a better way I should declare structs if they are more complex so that it is placed in memory where I want them to be? Is there a way to tell the structure what offset to use?

Comment: @Taako: Really, the only things you can do are to ensure that the offset of each element would be consistent with its alignment requirements without needing any padding, and to check that using `sizeof` yields the expected value.  If you lay out the structure so as not to require any compiler-generated padding (include your own dummy fields if needed), there will only be one way a compiler could lay out the structure with the correct size.  If the size is correct, the structure's layout will be as well.

Comment: @supercat C language is a C language defined by the standard document. There is nothing like a family of languages. All existing languages have evolved over the time. The compiler is not allowed to reorder the struct members and Structure members are stored sequentially  in the order in which they are declared: the first member has the lowest memory address and the last member the highest. Your answer is unfortunately wrong.

Comment: @Taako do not accept wrong answers (you did it in your both topics) as it may confuse the future readers. Comments are not indexed by google.

Comment: @PeterJ_01 then please make a correct answer so i can mark yours correct if you believe the answer i selected was wrong. Do not simply complain about my selection of answer if you aren't going to help make progress towards a final correct solution. Also please reference an official C document that says that compilers must declare struct members in order they are written in C.

Comment: @PeterJ_01: Dennis Ritchie created a language he called C, which evolved into a family of useful dialects as described in #1 long before there was any thought of an "official" Standards document.  The Standards Committee wrote a document that could be usefully regarded as describing a *common core* for such languages.  The Committee could not have intended that document to fully describe a useful language for freestanding implementations unless they were all morons or believed that `while(1);` was the only useful behavior anyone should need [can you identify *anything* else...

Comment: ...that a conforming freestanding implementation would be required to let programs do?]  Some people seem to think that any program which relies upon anything not mandated by the Standard is defective, but such an interpretation would imply that any freestanding program that performs any action whatsoever is defective.  Do you think that's what the authors of the Standard intended?